# plotly in R - specifying bin size for choropleth maps

Tags: r, plotly, choropleth

When creating a choropleth map using the plotly package in R, is there any way to specify the bin size?

Example:

```
library(plotly)
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv")
plot_ly(df, z=total.exports, locations=code, type="choropleth", locationmode="USA-states", colors = 'Purples', filename="", colorbar=list(title = "2011 US Agriculture Exports by State")) %>% 
layout(geo = list(scope="usa"))
```

Currently, the above code auto-bins into 2k steps. If I wanted say 5k steps and a max value of 30k, how would I do that? I was hoping there would be something like this (as there is with histograms):

`bins = list(start = 0, end = 30000, size = 5000)`

Comment: what plotly version are you using? latest 4.x only seems to support continuous variables for z, with a continuous colorbar legend. If your version supports categorical z values, then you could try `df$grp = cut(df$total.exports,c(0,5000,10000,15000...)` to generate your categories, then use the grp column to color the choropleth

Comment: Thank you! This helped. I had installed the package only a couple months ago but it seems like the latest version (4.x) has what I need. The code for those wondering is: plot_ly(df, z=~total.exports, locations=~code, zmin=0, zmax = 30000, type="choropleth", locationmode="USA-states", colors = 'Purples', filename="", colorbar=list(title = "2011 US Agriculture Exports by State")) %>% 
  layout(geo = list(scope="usa")). I also tried the categorical z values approach with df$grp but it seems like it produced a gray map. But the zmin/zmax approach also works so I'm fine with that

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @dww, using version 4.x:

```
plot_ly(df, z=~total.exports, locations=~code, zmin=0, zmax = 30000, type="choropleth", locationmode="USA-states", colors = 'Purples', filename="", colorbar=list(title = "2011 US Agriculture Exports by State")) %>% layout(geo = list(scope="usa"))
```