# Customize bin size in state_choropleth function in R?

Tags: r, legend, choropleth, choroplethr

I am trying to plot a map of the US in R, with state-level information metric (e.g., population). I want the states to be displayed in a color scale according to the metric to be plotted. I really liked the `state_choropleth()` function in the `choroplethr` package. However, I want to customize the state bin size. For example, when I use the following code:

```
library(choroplethr)
library(choroplethrMaps)
?df_pop_state
data(df_pop_state)
head(df_pop_state)
state_choropleth(df_pop_state)
```

I get the choropleth map and the legend shows 7 bins. The first bin has a range [562,803 to 1,052,471] and the last one has the range [11,533,561 to 37,325,068]. What if I want to set the bin sizes of the form [0 to 1,000,000]; [1,000,000 to 5,000,000]; ... and so on? I checked but I understand that there are no arguments for the `state_choropleth()` function that can be used to set the bin size.

I found this related question: [plotly in R - specifying bin size for choropleth maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856340/plotly-in-r-specifying-bin-size-for-choropleth-maps), and I tried using the `plot_ly()` example given in: https://plot.ly/r/choropleth-maps/#choropleth-maps-in-r. However, I am only able to see the legend and not the map in my RStudio as seen in the bottom right corner of the screenshot here: [Screenshot of plotly in RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Svz.jpg)

Any help/suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps adding an extra `scale_color_*` to [this line](https://github.com/cran/choroplethr/blob/da50bc5343ab909ec40263a9be93085760e18877/R/state.R#L38) would help?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, could you provide more hints? Line #38 adds geom_text() to the choropleth plot. Do you mean adding a new function `scale_color`? Thanks.

Comment: This is from a while back so the details are a bit blurry, but I think I was eluding to forking the package, modifying the function and using that.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik : thanks. I will try and share updates.

Comment: another option would be to make a continuous scale. `state_choropleth(df_pop_state,num_colors=1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
state_choropleth(df,
                 title = "title of the graph",
                 num_colors = 1) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low='white', 'high'='blue',limits=c(0,100000)) + 
  labs(fill = "title of the legend")
```

Make sure you set num_colors to 1.